# Convert To as a Next Stage in Custom Business Process Flow

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, business-process

I have to create BPF where the first entity is Mail and next is Opportunity. Is it possible to move to next stage by converting mail to opportunity instead of create?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve - You want to move the process-flow to Opportunity without creating it?

Comment: I thought about updating Opportunity processid and stageid fields. But it doesn't work. Probably because BPF state is stored in BusinessProcessFlowInstance table, which cannot be modified via SDK.